# Efficient way to add a condition-based column to a df

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

I have a large df with two columns:

```
Label                  Part_id
"Replace Cable"
"Ethernet Cable"       abc123
"Adjust Cable"
"Lubricate screw"
```

I wish to add a column "solution type", where will be "Part" whenever part_id is not null or Label has the words "replace"/"[p]", and Action when that is not the case.

Expected output will look like that:

```
Label                  Part_id       Solution Type
"Replace Cable"                      Part
"Ethernet Cable"       abc123        Part
"Adjust Cable"                       Action
"Lubricate screw"                    Action
```

I came up with the following code:

```
part_hints = r'(\[p\])|replace'

df['Solution Type'] = df.apply(lambda x: "Part" if not (pd.isnull(x.part_id)) or x.astype(str).str.contains(part_hints).any()
                                                else "Action", axis=1)
```

Problem is that it's really slow... For a df of 0.5M rows, this can take up to two minutes of runtime.

Would appreciate ideas for how to make this faster.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with `np.where()` :

```
import numpy as np

df["Solution Type"]=np.where(
        (df['Label'].str.contains(part_hints,case=False,regex=True)) | (df['Part_id'].notna()),
        "Part",
        "Action")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:

```
df.loc[df.Label.str.contains("replace", case=False) | df.Part_id.notnull(), 'Solution Type'] = 'Part'

df["Solution Type"].fillna("Action", inplace = True)
```